# Python 3.3.3 code shortening

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a section of python code that I need to repeat but only changing two things, is there a way to shorten this?

The code:

```
if int(input)==1:
    output=10
if int(input)==2:
    output=9
```

All the way to

```
  if int(input)==88:
        output=-77
```

Is there a way of shortening this

Comment: Isn't that just `output = 11 - int(input)`?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try using something like this, its a type of loop which you can set
the amount of times it runs. You may need to change this a bit though to your circumstances

```
    n = 1
    while n <= 'number of your choice':
        n += 1
        # And you would then do what ever calculations you want here
```

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't suggest this at all. Seems like a lot of work to use a loop, given @jonsharpe's solution. even then, would it not be more useful to use a for loop?